# Link to detail page of tt_news is not updated

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, tt-news, realurl

I edited the title of the news:

Old link:
www.domain.com/news/article/some-article-name.html

New link:
www.domain.com/news/article/test.html

Now I wanted to change the title back to get a URL like this
www.domain.com/news/article/some-article-name.html

but I still get the old URL:
www.domain.com/news/article/test.html

I generate my link to a tt_news detail page as follows:

```
$typolink_conf = array(
    "title" => '',
    "ATagParams" =>'',
    "no_cache" => 0,
    "parameter" => 25,
    "additionalParams" => '&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=' . $data['uid'],
    "useCacheHash" => 0
);

$link = $this->cObj->typolink_URL($typolink_conf);
$link = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['config.']['baseURL'] . $link;
```

I already tried to clear all caches, clear the cache from real_url and so on. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That must be a cache problem. Did you also delete the unique aliases for tt_news?

Go to:

> Web -> Info -> RealUrl management -> Show: Unique Aliases -> tt_news

And delete all or your specific news from this list.